# Py.test command not found, but library is installed

Tags: terminal, command, pip, pytest

There are already two posts on stack overflow on this topic; however, none of them have resolved or addressed my specific situation.

I have installed pytest via `pip install pytest`.  I am able to import the library in Python as well.

The problem is that when I try to use the `py.test` command in Terminal, I get `py.test: command not found`.

Does anyone have any insight as to why I am not able to use the command in the terminal?

EDIT:  It even shows up as an installed package:

```
$ pip list
cycler (0.9.0)
matplotlib (1.5.1)
numpy (1.10.1)
pip (8.1.0)
py (1.4.31)
pyparsing (2.0.7)
pytest (2.9.0)
python-dateutil (2.4.2)
pytz (2015.7)
scipy (0.17.0)
setuptools (7.0)
six (1.10.0)
tensorflow (0.5.0)
vboxapi (1.0)
wheel (0.26.0)
```

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? If so, `pip` (at least older versions) will not install the `py.test` binary if it's already installed systemwide. You can use `python -m pytest` instead.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

using `python -m pytest` will work for you.

Or if you using virtual environment and installed pytest on virtualenv you should then run py.test alongside your virtual environment.

Check this website can be useful:http://pythontesting.net/framework/pytest/pytest-introduction/

Comment: What is the meaning of `-m`?

Comment: @YanKingYin Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821312/meaning-of-python-m-flag/50821426

Comment: @YanKingYin "When the -m flag is used with a command on the command-line interface, followed by a <module_name>, it allows the module to be executed as an executable file". More here: [What Is The Meaning Of Python M Flag?](https://appdividend.com/2021/02/18/what-is-the-meaning-of-python-m-flag/)

Answer (score 17):

I already had the latest version of pytest on macOS with Homebrew-installed Python 2.7 and this fixed it:

```
pip uninstall pytest
pip install pytest
```

Answer (score 12):

Are you on a mac with homebrew by any chance?

I had the same issue and it basically came down to permissions/conflict with the mac os base installed python.  pip install would not install or link stuff into /usr/local/bin (it happened with both virtualenv and pytest).

1. I uninstalled python 2.7 completely with homebrew (`brew uninstall python`).
2. Next, I reinstalled python with homebrew to fix pip (it was not a symlink in /usr/local/bin/pip where it should have been linked to Cellar) -- `brew install python`
3. Then I uninstalled pip with *sudo* -- `sudo python -m pip uninstall pip` to remove the pip owned by root
4. Now I uninstalled and reinstalled python with homebrew again to reinstall pip with the correct permissions `brew uninstall python && brew install python`
5. Next I fixed the python symlinks `brew link python`
6. Finally, `pip install pytest` worked! (and so did `pip install virtualenv`)

I found the information in the chosen answer from this post very helpful:
https://superuser.com/questions/915810/pip-not-working-on-hombrew-python-2-7-install.

If you're not on a mac, sorry for the noise...

Comment: This worked for me on a Mac. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Worked for me - thanks. Lots of Mac issues with recent disto upgrades

Answer (score 5):

This answer assumes that you have python3 and pip3 - if not remove 3 from the commands in this answer.

After installing pytest and confirming that it is available in your python environment with `pip3 show pytest` command, if you are still getting the error like `zsh:command not found:pytest`. You have a few options:

Option 1. Run the library as a module with `python3 -m pytest`.

Option 2. Create a permanent solution by simply creating an alias. To create an alias, follow these steps:

i) Find the location of your shell profile file by running `echo $SHELL`. The following are the potential locations of your shell profiles:

- Bash: ~/.bashrc
- Zsh: ~/.zshrc
- Ksh: ~/.profile

For instance, when I run on my Mac terminal I get: `/bin/zhs`. This means that in the next step I need to refer to the `~/.zshrc` file.

ii) Once you figure out the name of your shell profile file. Run `echo "alias pytest='python3 -m pytest'" >> ~/.zshrc`. This will append the alias definition, which in this case is 'pytest', to your shell profile file.

iii) Finally, reload your profile file by writing this command: `source ~/.zshrc`.

Happy Testing!!!

Answer (score 1):

I may be late, but while exploring this I noticed that this can be because the Scripts folder for python is not present in the PATH.

For me this is my scripts folder:

```
C:\Python38\Scripts\
```

If the path is a problem then running `pip install pytest` should actually you give you the warning with the path it was added to.

This should be present in the path. If on windows, edit the environment variables and this location to the PATH.

For me the path was incorrect because of an improper installation of python

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04, following [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/5213#issuecomment-489408755):

I checked that `pytest` was in `~/.local/bin`, and noticed this path wasn't in the `$PATH` variable. I edited `~/.bashrc` and added the following line at the end:

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/.local/bin"
```

I then ran the command `source ~/.bashrc` to reload the `~/.bashrc` profile in the current `bash` terminal, ran the command `pytest`, and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had pytest v2.8.3 installed and the binary *was* on my path but under the name `py.test`. Upgrading to v3.0.3 added the regular `pytest` executable to the path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have changed the Python installed folder permission to full access. And then uninstalled the pytest and installed again.

pip uninstall pytest

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a similar issue in ubuntu 20.04. The below solution worked for me.
Cause: Shell remembers the previous version or previously used `Path`, hence we need to force the shell to 'forget' the old location - with `-r`

```
hash -r pytest
```

Then execute the tests it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For MAC users:

Download python universal installer for mac:
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.5/python-3.10.5-macos11.pkg

Then try to install **pytest** module in terminal using this command:

**pip install pytest**

Hope this will fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: the question is not about how to install pytest, OP already has done that, please read the problem carefully.

Answer (score 0):

use  the command, pip install -U pytest and install it in your cmd prompt, it will solve the issue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blbKp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I used macbook air m2, and the way I deal with this problem is:
Command in terminal in macbook:

> which pytest

**/opt/anaconda3/bin/pytest** -> my terminal shows this

Then you got the path of pytest, in the "Command", before "pytest", add its path and following with the path of python file you wanna test.

> **/opt/anaconda3/bin/pytest**  /Users/cindyng/Desktop/Testing.py

Done, and if you cannot find the path of python in macbook, "which python" also helps, and you can put it in "Home" and "Custom Python Builder".

Hope that helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1. Install pytest: If you haven't already installed pytest, you can install it using a package manager like pip. Run the following command in your terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash
 pip install pytest
```

This command will install pytest and its dependencies.

Check your PATH: Make sure that the directory containing the pytest executable is included in your PATH environment variable. You can check your current PATH by running the following command:

```
 echo $PATH
```

If the directory containing pytest is not included in your PATH, you can add it by editing your shell configuration file (e.g. ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc) and adding the following line:

```
#!/bin/bash
 export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/pytest
```

Replace "/path/to/pytest" with the actual path to the directory containing pytest.

Check your shell: Make sure that you are running the correct shell and that it is configured correctly. If you are using zsh, make sure that your shell configuration file (e.g. ~/.zshrc) contains the necessary configuration for pytest. For example, you may need to add the following line to your ~/.zshrc file:

```
#!/bin/bash
 autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```

This line ensures that zsh's or bash's  tab completion system is set up correctly for pytest.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you installed it without Administrator credentials, like when using,

```
pip install pytest --user
```

This will install it in a local folder instead of the main folder defined on the windows Path Environment Variables.

Open a windows terminal as Administrator, and then uninstall the installed `pytest` and install it again, like this:

```
pip uninstall pytest
pip install pytest
```

So, always install packages with Administrator credentials in order to be in the right path!

Answer (score -1):

I Fixed this issue via below steps.
1.First uninstall existing pytest.
2.Check python version.
3.then verify pytest version is supported with python version or not via github issue tracker.
4. via sudo install pytest
sudo pip install pytest
5. verify pytest version and insatlled correctly or not.
pip list
pytest --version

6.run any test using pytest test_abc.py

Answer (score -2):

I encounter the same problem, `python -m pytest` works for me.

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36006909/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*