# Difference between 'python -m pip install <package-name>' and 'pip install <package-name>'

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to run a Django application within a virtual environment but it kept showing me errors regarding missing packages that need installation although I did install them previously using `pip install <package-name>`.

The issues couldn't be resolved until I used `python -m pip install <package-name>` to install the missing packages.

My question is what is the difference between the two commands? Does one of the commands install packages to the virtual environment and the other one does that globally? I'm confused.

Side Note: Also when running `pip freeze` shows different installed packages than those showing when I run `python -m pip freeze`.

---

**Update No.1:**

Running `pip list -v` shows that the packages installed using `pip install <package-name>` are located inside the **virtual environment** folder under `lib/python3.8/site-packages` directory, while running `python -m pip list -v` shows that the packages installed using `python -m pip <package-name>` are located under `/usr/lib/<python3 or python3.8>/<site-packages or dist-packages>` directory.

---

**Update No.2:**

I experienced all of the above using a VPS that is running Ubuntu 20.04 64 bit. The weird thing is that when I'm on my local machine that is running Linux Mint, executing both commands does the exact same thing, there is no difference between `pip install <package-name>` and `python -m pip install <package-name>` on my local machine.

---

**Update No.3:**

What I did is that I removed my virtual environment and created a new one with the same name and in the same directory.
To make things clearer, the following screenshots demonstrate the issue I'm facing:

1- The below screenshot shows the result of `pip list -v` when I run it globally:
[image]

2- The below screenshot shows the result of `python -m pip list -v` when I run it globally:
[image]

The above 2 screenshots are showing the same result (both commands are executed globally, no active virtual environment).

3- The below screenshot shows the result of `pip list -v` when I run it inside my virtual environment:

[image]

4- The below screenshot shows the result of `python -m pip list -v` when I run it inside my virtual environment:

[image]

The above 2 screenshots show different results (both commands are executed while the virtual environment is activated).

The issue still persists although I created a new virtual environment.

Comment: What's the output of `pip -V` and `python -m pip -V` in your system?

Comment: @AlejandroBlasco Running `pip --version` returned the following result:
`pip 20.0.2 from /root/<project-name>/my-virtual-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)`,
while running `python -m pip --version` returned the following:
`pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)`

Comment: Go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821312/meaning-of-python-m-flag One of the examples is on pip only

Comment: @soumya-kole ALready done that but didn't find it very helpful.

Comment: The question seems to have morphed into a completely different one

Comment: @mousetail No its all circling around the same thing, where the packages are getting installed.

Comment: If you say `which python`  outside the virtualenv and inside the virutalenv do they return the same path? If so, the the `activate` is not updating the path and you will need to do it manually by running `hash -r` after you `activate` your virtualenv

Comment: @JavierBuzzi They are returning different pathes.

Comment: what about `pip` also can you show what the paths are?

Comment: @JavierBuzzi pip showed the same path in both commands

Comment: Can you update the question and say what they are?

Answer (score 3):

*Welcome to the world of symlinks, binary discoverability with `PATH`, and shebang `#!/...` (*nix).*

Before getting into the weaves of it all, let's talk about what `pip` is:

`pip` is both a python module (i.e `python -m pip` (the `-m` mean module)) and a binary `$ pip`. `pip` as a binary (the program) is optional, it's not required. `pip` as the module (inside `site-packages` where all the python modules are installed) is ABSOLUTELY required! Without it nothing will work, or worse yet you would use the `pip` module from another python version you have installed and then you're really going to slam your head against the wall...

#### PATH variable

`echo $PATH` (*nix) will show you something like this:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

That means that the system, through the terminal will look for the binaries first inside `/usr/local/bin` then `/usr/bin` then ... so on. If it found it in the first place it looked, great, it's done, no need to keep searching. You can have the same binary name in different directories, the order of `PATH` is what matters, the second one will never be executed, EVER.

Why am I mentioning this? Well let's say you installed multiple versions of `python` or `pip`, and you installed it in the wrong place? Where the order is wrong? Well that binary will not run as expected.

#### Symlinks

You can have different versions of `pip` and `python` -- they're independent from one another, meaning just because you're using `python` with version 3.8, does not mean your `pip` is pointing to the same python binary.

A quick way to check is to do: (this applies to `pip`)

```
$ ls -ls $(which python)
0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  75 Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/python -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

You can see it's using the system version of `python` and any other version I have are being ignored if I just run `python`, I can "fix" this by specifying the version number such as `python3.8`...

You can fix this one by first figuring out what binaries you have available to you:

```
$ echo $PATH | sed 's/:/ /g' | xargs -n1 -I{} find {} -name 'python*' | grep -v 'config$'
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3.9
/usr/local/bin/python3.8
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2
/usr/bin/pythonw
/usr/bin/pythonw2.7
/usr/bin/python2.7
```

Say I want my default `python` to be `python3.8`, then do:

```
$ ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/local/bin/python
$ hash -r
```

*`hash -r` tells the the terminal to forget all the banaries it found before, otheriwise your new symlink will not work*

##### Q. Why not just override it?

The astute among you might ask, if the default `python` is inside `/usr/bin/python` why not just override it using?

```
$ ln -sf /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python
```

`/usr/bin/` is protected, and it's bad form to mess around with system prefernces. It's best not to touch it, `/usr/local/bin` is yours (the user of the machine) to mess with.

#### Shebang `#!/...`

For the most part you will find the `pip` binary  file (thats just plain text by the way) to start like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.9
```

This says, i'm a text file that needs to be ran with the following executable. In the first example, it's using the system to fin the binary `python` the same way you would find it in the terminal, see `PATH` variable above. The second example is a direct path to the binary for the system to use.

Remember `pip` is a module, the binary `pip` literaly says this: (this is slighly modified to make it as basic as possible and illustrate a point)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from pip._internal.cli.main import main
sys.exit(main())
```

1. use the `python` binary
2. import the `sys` module to be used later...
3. import the `main` function from the `pip` module
4. run `main`, what ever code it returns pass it to `sys.exit(..)` usually will return `0` but thats neighter here nor there.. just an FYI

Comment: Okay so I really appreciate your effort. I understood your answer. But I wasn't able to find where your answer solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference typically.

The `python -m` flag allows you to run a specific module. For example you can run `python -m http.server` to start a simple server in the current directory.

Python includes a "scripts" directory. Depending on your system setup, modules from the `scripts` directory can be run directly from the shell without the `python -m` prefix. For example, typically you run `black` directly from the shell.

However, there are various reasons you might not want to trust running python modules directly from the shell, including:

- Running a specific python version. You can do `py -3.6 -m pip install something` to specify a python version
- You don't want to add the scripts folder to your PATH for whatever reason. Maybe because some names conflict with other programs on your computer.

Inside a virtualenv both commands will typically do the same thing, since `virtualenv` will properly set your PATH

Comment: But what is the reason that each command installs packages in different directories? Shouldn't they install packages to the same location?

Comment: They will not install in different locations if both use the same python installation. (same version, same virtualenv). If it's different it will install in a different location.

Comment: Somtimes when updating/modifying python exiting vitualenvironments stop working properly. If you are experiencing issues with virutalenv try deleting the environment and creating it again

Comment: Alright, I will try that

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty handy when you need to define which python version you need your package to be installed to (sorry for my bad english).
Say, you have both python3.8 and python3.10.
You can do `python3.8 -m pip install django` and `python3.10 -m pip install django`

Comment: In my case both commands are using the same version of python (python3.8)