# standalone Python installed, try to run pip install and got : "Relative module names not supported"

Tags: python, pip

On a distant server on *Rocky8*, as I needed recent Python and as I don't have admin privileges to install with *sudo*, finally I succeeded to build and install Python 3.11 on my local home.

When I invoke `python3.11` or run a script all is fine, my issue is with `pip install` !

This is the tree for Python 3.11 and pip:

```
Python311/
    bin/
        2to3-3.11
        idle3.11
        pip3.11
        pydoc3.11
        python3.11
        python3.11-config 
    lib/
        python3.11/
            site-packages/
                pip/
                    __init__.py
                    _internal
                    __main__.py
                    __pip-runner__.py
                    __pycache__
                    py.typed
                    _vendor
```

I didn't yet create any alias or added anything to `PYTHONPATH`.

If I do:

```
$HOME/tools/Python311/bin/pip3.11 --version
```

I got as expected:

```
pip 22.3.1 from /tr2dev01/tr2/tools/Python311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
```

and

```
$HOME/tools/Python311/bin > ./python3.11 -m ensurepip
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /tr2dev01/tr2/tools/python/Python311/lib/python3.11/site-packages (65.5.0)

Requirement already satisfied: pip in /tr2dev01/tr2/tools/python/Python311/lib/python3.11/site-packages (22.3.1)
```

The issue is when I run:

```
$HOME/tools/Python311/bin > ./python3.11 -m ./pip3.11 install numpy
```

got:

```
/tr2dev01/tr2/tools/Python311/bin/python3.11: Relative module names not supported
```

Or:

```
$HOME/tools/Python311 > ./bin/python3.11 -m ./lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip install numpy
```

got:

```
/tr2dev01/tr2/tools/Python311/bin/python3.11: Relative module names not supported
```

Is my directory tree structure good?

What is the correct syntax? What is required for it to work?

Comment: `./python3.11 -m ./pip3.11` is incorrect. It has to be `./python3.11 -m pip`, the `-m pip` part is always the same whatever Python interpreter you use. https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running something like `./python3.11 -m ./pip3.11` is incorrect. What you want to do is `./python3.11 -m pip`. The `-m pip` notation will instruct the Python interpreter to look for `site-packages/pip/__main__.py` and run it.

***Related***:

- [Meaning of python -m flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821312/meaning-of-python-m-flag)
- [What is the purpose of the -m switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610001/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-m-switch)
- https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m
- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: indeed, it was so simple, it works !!
thanks a lot !!