# Installed pytest but running `pytest` in bash returns `not found`

Tags: python, django, vagrant, pytest, pytest-django

I am following the [python-django](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) tutorial in Vagrant (Ubuntu 18.04 / Python3.6.6). After running `pip3 install pytest-django` and configuring `pytest.ini` file, running `pytest` returns

```
Command 'pytest' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install python-pytest
Please ask your administrator.
```

`pip3 freeze` output:

```
pytest==3.10.0
pytest-django==3.4.3
```

Is there something else to the installation?

Comment: Try python -m pytest

Comment: yup that worked. make it an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Py.test command not found, but library is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35998992/py-test-command-not-found-but-library-is-installed)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try python -m pytest

Installing pytest via pip doesn't make it a system command, it installs it to python.  The -m command runs pytest as its own command and then any proceeding script will be an argument.

Answer (score 0):

I got problem when I wanted to run the following code in .sh file.

```
pytest-3 -s test.py
```

To solve it I get solution from linux itself as follows:

```
sudo apt install python3-pytest
```